# how to show session is about to timeout dialog before 1 min in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, session-timeout, shiro

I am trying to show session is about to timeout dialog in my `shiro` based application here is my code what i tried but its not working yet...

```
   <%
        Subject user = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        Session usersession = user.getSession(true);
        if(user.isAuthenticated()){

                    Date startTime = usersession.getStartTimestamp(); //login time
                    Date lastAccessTime = usersession.getLastAccessTime(); //last active time
                    Date currentTime = new Date(); // current time
                    long diffInSec = (currentTime.getTime()- lastAccessTime.getTime())/1000 ; // calculate idle time of user
                    long timeout = (long)(usersession.getTimeout()* 0.001); // get sessiontime out in seconds
                    long oneMinleft = timeout - 60 ; // get time to show timeout dialog before 1 min of session timeout
                    System.out.println("startTime :"+startTime);
                    System.out.println("lastAccessTime :"+lastAccessTime);
                    System.out.println("currentTime :"+currentTime);
                    System.out.println("diffInSec :"+diffInSec);
                    System.out.println("Timeout:"+timeout);
                    System.out.println("Seconds left to timeout:"+oneMinleft);
                    System.out.println();

                        if(diffInSec >= oneMinleft){ %>
                          <script type="text/javascript">                                
                                    showTimeout(); // show dialog
                          </script>
                       <% 
                        }
        }

    %>
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks & regards

Comment: what is error? we can't understand your problem if you din't provide your code.

Comment: diffInSec always comes 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing that in JSP, so it is executed when the user is making a request so it is not idle and the session-timeout restarts.
You may do something similar in javascript so the time runs when the user is doing nothing.

You can mix JSP and javascript this way:

```
setTimeout(function(){showTimeout()},<%= session.getMaxInactiveInterval() - 60*1000 %>);
```

You don't need lastAccessTime since you know it always be 0 when attending a request.

Comment: I created new Filter wrote above code inside doFilter method then also its giving me " diffInsec as 0 "

Comment: @Sumit Filters are run on request too. You need to show the message in client when the user is doing nothing so you need something running on the client. Javascript is the easiest way.

Comment: Don't use this as is if it is normal that this page remains open and the session expiration is prevented by requests done with ajax or in popups. It would warn the user while it would be false that the session was going to expire.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript code for this.

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("alert message to show")},timeInMilliseconds);
```