# Display a warning before session expires in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session

I need that JSP display a warning message when the session expires. I use the following XML code:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I think this question was asked so many times but i didn't found a exact solution.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324873/how-to-show-session-is-about-to-timeout-dialog-before-1-min-in-jsp) might help you

Answer (score 1):

You can try following logic.

- Create a timeout, which has execution time = Session Timeout - difference before triggering alert.
- Tap the user events like key press, click etc. and set the flag (USER_ACTION) to true.
- Check for a flag (USER_ACTION) to identify is user has performed an action. If flag is false, show alert. Else has to result in initiating timeout again and reset the flag (USER_ACTION) to false.

Comment: since i am not strong in JavaScript i could not able to implement your logic can you help me this?

Answer (score 0):

Just call a function every5 seconds or so that checks one of the session variables and see if its value is null. If it is you know the session has expired

```
setInterval(isTimedOut(), 5000);

function isTimedOut() {
   var isLoggedIn = '<%Session["someValue"] != null%>';

   if (session == false) {
       //display warning here
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i would like to show a warning before the expiry of session i.e if session expires at 10th minute i want to display a warning at the 9th minute

Comment: Though the JS function will be called in interval, the value for JSP scriptlet will be stamped once.